# How many possible combinations of 9 digits are there as long as they follow a certain set of rules?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, divisibility

The digits 1-9 are labelled a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>9</sub> such that:

a<sub>1</sub> is a multiple of 1.

a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub> is a multiple of 2 (here and throughout the digits are concatenated rather than multiplied - so if a<sub>1</sub> is 4 and a<sub>2</sub> is 3 then
a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub> = 43 and not 12).

a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub> is a multiple of 3.

a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>4</sub> is a multiple of 4.

And so on until a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>5</sub>a<sub>6</sub>a<sub>7</sub>a<sub>8</sub>a<sub>9</sub>.

---

1. Can you find a suitable arrangement of the digits?
2. How many possibilities are there?

---

I began forming a few rules, so I had:

a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>4</sub>, a<sub>6</sub>, a<sub>8</sub> must all be even.

a<sub>5</sub> must be 5.

a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub> = multiple of 3.

a<sub>4</sub> + a<sub>6</sub> = 10.

Using these rules, I managed to answer the first question and got the arrangement 381654729.

For Part 2, I was thinking of listing them all out, but I was hoping there is a shorter and faster method to approach this.

Comment: Why is $a_4 + a_6$ a multiple of $10$?

Comment: No, it must add up to 10.

Comment: What I am asking is what rule justifies that conclusion?

Comment: So a_4 + a_5 + a_6 must be equal to a multiple of 3. We know that a_5 is always going to be 5, so a_4 + a_6 must be 10.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cut down on how many cases you need to examine note that since $8\mid a_1\dots a_8$, $8\mid a_6a_7a_8$. This, together with the distinct-digits condition, alternating even and odd digits ($a_{\text{odd}}$ is odd, $a_{\text{even}}$ is even) and $a_7\ne5$, restricts $a_6a_7a_8$ to $12$ possibilities:
$$216,296,416,432,472,496,632,672,816,832,872,896$$
But now note that $a_6$ cannot be $2$ or $6$, as that would make $a_4$ $4$ or $8$. Since $4\mid a_1a_2a_3a_4$, $4\mid a_3a_4$ and $a_4$ being $4$ or $8$ would force $a_3$ to be even, which it cannot be. The $12$ possibilities are reduced to $8$:
$$416,432,472,496,816,832,872,896$$
Then of course $a_6+a_8\ne10$, otherwise $a_4=a_8$. We go down to four possibilities:
$$432,472,816,896$$
Now suppose $a_6=8$. We get the partial $?4?258?6?$; since $1,7,4$ are $1\bmod3$ and $3,9$ are $0\bmod3$, $a_1,a_7$ must be $1,7$ in some order, $a_7=9$ and $a_9=3$. But neither $1472589$ nor $7412589$ are divisible by $7$, so any solution satisfies the following partial:
$$?8?654?2?$$
Casework should now be small enough to do by hand and show that $381654729$ is the *only* solution.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 8∣a1…a8 , 8∣a6a7a8 and 1mod3 ?

Comment: @luzeoid Standard notation. $a\mid b$ means $b$ is divisible by $a$.

Comment: Thanks, and how about modulus?

Comment: @luzeoid Suppose $a=qm+b$ has a solution all in integers, then we can say $a\equiv b\bmod m$. That is equivalent to saying $m\mid(a-b)$.